# Is VMware Horizon Client available to download on Unbutu

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, vmware

I am new to Ubuntu on raspberry Pi 4 and am wondering if VMware Horizon Client is supported for the 20.10 version? If, so can you provide instructions on how to download?

Comment: Have you tried to follow https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Horizon-Client-for-Linux/5.5/rn/horizon-client-linux-55-release-notes.html ?